# Bug after commenting

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, mobile-app

> [image: Screen mentioned]

After commenting I get redirected to a white blank page.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 12.0.1 (Build 16A404)